# Rename a component of R lists

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, return-value

```
l1 <- list(a = 'FirstComponent', b= 'SecondComponent')
```

To rename the first component from `a` to `c` I can do this:

```
names(l1) <- c('c', 'b')
```

Or this:

```
names(l1)[1] <- c('c')
```

But not this:

```
names(l1[1]) <- c('c')
```

Nor this:

```
names(l1[[1]]) <- c('c')
```

Why wouldn't the third and fourth code example work? They also try to rename an R object `l1[1]` and `l1[[1]]`. What's happening behind the scene?

=========Following is part of the original question===========

> R documentation: it is possible to update just part of the names attribute via the general rules: see the examples. This works because the expression there is evaluated as `z <- "names<-"(z, "[<-"(names(z), 3, "c2"))`.

The returned value of `names(z)` in `"[<-"(names(z), 3, "c2")` is passed to the next function as a parameter, which is `"[<-"`.

Comment: For your first question, everything can become a function in R for example you can assign variables like this`"<-"(iris$new_var,1); head(iris)` - (Note I put quotes instead of backticks as it is tricky to show backticks in comments)

Comment: Thanks! I soon figured that out after posting the question. I'll edit my question to make it focus on the second one.

Comment: even getting source code of `names` function is a tedious task !!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking at three different functions: `<-`, `[<-` and `names<-`. What is happening will be clear once you understand what each of these does.

The assignment operator `<-` takes two arguments, a variable name and value, and assigns the value to that variable. So `` `<-`(x, 'y') `` has the same effect as `x <- 'y'`.

`[<-` can take many arguments, but the ones you are interested in are the variable, the index, and the value. It assigns the value specified to the index of the vector stored in the variable and returns the result. So for example if `a <- c(1, 2, 3)`, then `` `[<-`(a, 2, 10) `` will return (a copy of) the vector `a`, having replaced its second entry with 10.

`names<-` is a function which takes two arguments, a list and a vector of names, and assigns these names to the list. 
So `` `names<-`(l1, c('a', 'b')) `` is just another way of writing `names(l1) <- c('a', 'b')`.

What the documentation is telling you, is how the function `names<-` is defined, based on the definition of `[<-`. What happens in
`` z <- `names<-`(z, `[<-`(names(z), 3, "c2")) `` is:

1. Start e.g. with `z = list('a' = 1, 'b' = 2, 'c' = 3)`. First, get the names of z:

   ```
   nz <- names(z)  # c("a", "b", "c")
   ```
2. Replace the 3rd entry of `nz` with "c2" and return the result

   ```
   nznew <- `[<-`(nz, 3, "c2")  # c("a", "b", "c2")
   ```
3. Replace the names of `z` with `nznew` and return the result

   ```
   z <- `names<-`(z, nznew)
   ```

Why does `names(l1[1]) <- 'c'` not work? It actually does, but it does not replace the first element of the list. When you call `l1[1]`, its value is returned into a new variable (which is a list consisting only of the first component of `l1`) and then the names of that variable are modified (but not assigned to anything!). Try for example

```
x <- l1[1]
names(x) <- 'c'
```

and see how the names of `x` have changed. Or, in one step, `` x <- `names<-`(l1[1], 'c') ``.

Why does `names(l1[[1]]) <- 'c'` not work? Well, same reason as above, plus `l1[[1]]` actually returns the contents of the first element of `l1` which may not even have a `names` attribute.